Terraform error on ebs_csi_addon creation

Error: waiting for EKS Add-On (dataflow:aws-ebs-csi-driver) create: unexpected state 'CREATE_FAILED', wanted target 'ACTIVE'. last error: : UnsupportedAddonModification: DaemonSet.apps "ebs-csi-node" is invalid: spec.selector: Invalid value: v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"app":"ebs-csi-node", "app.kubernetes.io/name":"aws-ebs-csi-driver", MatchExpressions:v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil): field is immutable.

resource "aws_eks_addon" "ebs_csi_addon" {
  cluster_name = var.eks_cluster_name
  addon_name   = "aws-ebs-csi-driver"
  resolve_conflicts_on_create = "OVERWRITE"
  service_account_role_arn = module.ebs_csi_eks_role.iam_role_arn
  depends_on = [ aws_eks_cluster.eks-cluster, aws_eks_node_group.eks-ng]
}

Any changes needed in this code?
